# create shapefile from pdf site plan to plot data with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, spatial, cad

Using ggplot2 I'm trying to overlay information on pdfs of property suite plans like the one linked to below. The idea is to color code different suites based on certain metrics associated with each suite.

https://business.simon.com/assets/mall/1324/LEASING_PLAN/7964_FLORIDA%20KEYS%20OUTLET%20MKTPLACE_CurrentWebLeasePlan-1_1.pdf

Can anyone recommend how I can create a spatial data representation of the PDF that tags the individual suites? I'd ideally like to do this without commercial software like AutoCAD.

For reference, this tutorial shows how to make the plots once you have a shape file representation of a map.

http://www.kevjohnson.org/making-maps-in-r/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That PDF seems to have enough geospatial info to be readable by the `OGR` library, which you can access via the `sf` package:

```
> library(sf)
> plan = st_read("./7964_FLORIDA KEYS OUTLET MKTPLACE_CurrentWebLeasePlan-1_1.pdf")
Reading layer `~Remaining_objects' from data source `/home/rowlings/Downloads/SO/7964_FLORIDA KEYS OUTLET MKTPLACE_CurrentWebLeasePlan-1_1.pdf' using driver `PDF'
Simple feature collection with 998 features and 0 fields
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 71.1875 ymin: 52.47917 xmax: 2478.271 ymax: 1613.917
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
```

There's 998 assorted features in there - lines, polygons etc. You can plot it:

```
> plot(plan$geometry)
Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) : 
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4.
```

and ignore the error for now. The coordinate system isn't earth-referenced though, its got a (0,0) origin on the bottom left:

```
> axis(1)
> axis(2)
```

[image]

If you want you can extract parts of the plan and just plot those:

```
> plot(plan[1:100,])
```

[image]

but there's no metadata about what features are what things. All you have is the geometry. Is a "suite" just one room? You'll have

You can use `geom_sf` from `ggplot` to map this, but when it fails with that error it plots nothing:

```
> ggplot(plan) + geom_sf()
Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) : 
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4.
```

I tracked the error down to feature number 638, so eliminate that if you want to use `ggplot`:

```
> ggplot(plan[-638,]) + geom_sf()
>
```

I think that's as much as you can get out of this PDF automatically. If you want to code the names of the areas from the text in the PDF that will be tricky. The text isn't read in by `OGR` and the onyl way I can think is to use a PDF-to-Text converter to get the text and its location, then match up the locations with the polygon features, but that might not work because the coordinate systems likely don't match.... So it might be easier to do it by hand. Load the PDF into QGIS (which should work because it uses `OGR`) and then create new columns in the attribute table and go through each one adding the store names and info. Then you can save to a shapefile (or better, a geopackage) which you can read into R and map with ggplot...

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. Yes, the suites are just the individual rooms on the plan. I think QGIS is the way to go. This plan had readable data but the others I need to process are raster files.